# How to open Google Chrome or Safari from Terminal

Tags: terminal, safari, google-chrome

When I try to open 'chrome' or 'safari' in terminal,

```
$ safari
-bash: safari: command not found
$ open safari
The file Desktop/safari does not exist.
$ chrome
-bash: chrome: command not found
```

How to open them in right methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its trying to open the files from the Desktop folder. Safari is in the Applications folder. From the top level / you should type `open Applications/safari` This works fine for me.  cd up to / and do ls. The Application folder should show up. If not you are in the wrong directory.

Comment: All you need to do in **Terminal**, no mater what the `PWD`, is use `open -a Safari` or `open -a Google\ Chrome` and if wanted, add the **URL** afterwards if you want to open the **Browser** to the given **URL**. You do not need the type the `pathname` or the `.app` _extension_.

Comment: Does not work in Monterey (12.5.1) `The file /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Applications/safari does not exist.`

Answer (score 22):

All you need to do in Terminal, no matter what directory you're in, is use

```
open -a Safari
open -a Google\ Chrome
```

and optionally, add the URL afterwards if you want to open the Browser to the given URL

```
open -a Safari http://apple.com/
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Monterey. `open -a Safari http://apple.com/` opens apple.com in both Safari AND Chrome. Chrome is my default browser. `open -a Safari\ Technology\ Preview http://apple.com/` does work and only opens the site in Safari Technology Preview. `open -a Firefox http://www.google.com/dogs` opens Firefox if it not already opened, but does not go to the site on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you could do it. But first, if `Safari` is your default browser, then you can just use this to open the URL:
`open <url>` => `open http://www.google.com` (Remember to specify the protocol!) and this will open the URL in Safari (default browser)

Otherwise you can be more specific like:

```
/usr/bin/open https://google.com/
```

And to open a sepecific browser, you can do

```
/usr/bin/open -a Safari https://google.com/
/usr/bin/open -a Firefox https://google.com/
/usr/bin/open -a Chrome https://google.com/
```

Comment: `/usr/bin` is in the typical search path, there is hardly ever a need to specific this.

Comment: I sometimes faced issues when trying to open a web browser with `open` when I was in some directory other than root and adding the exact path worked every time for me. I even added a small function in my `.zshrc` file to open a URL in all browsers for testing a URL.

Answer (score -1):

as of os 10.11.6, you may use:

`open http://github.com` to open in default browser.

Comment: The answer is not perfect, does not include safari and chrome, but the question was not specific to use `and`. This is the easiest way, worth knowing. Negative score is wrong.